# Rails Query Unique Items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search bar which works fine but it produces a duplicate every time it shows the correct result.

```
if params[:nav_search] 
  @art = Art.where(["style_number LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:nav_search]}%", "%#{params[:nav_search]}%"]).page(params[:page]).per_page(18)
end
```

Any clue where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I don't know what is going wrong. you are probably joining another table somewhere. Adding the output of the executed query could help. Adding `.distinct` after the `where` will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to the following

```
@art = Art.where(["style_number LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:nav_search]}%", "%#{params[:nav_search]}%"]).distinct.page(params[:page]).per_page(18)
```

To retrieve objects from the database, Active Record provides several finder methods. Each finder method allows you to pass arguments into it to perform certain queries on your database without writing raw SQL.

You can see this [`Rails Guide`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database) for very well understand

Answer (score 0):

include **.uniq**

try this,

```
if params[:nav_search] 
  @art = Art.where(["style_number LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:nav_search]}%", "%#{params[:nav_search]}%"]).uniq.page(params[:page]).per_page(18)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `uniq` or `distinct` to avoid duplicate records. In your case, you should use `distinct`:

```
if params[:nav_search] 
  @art = Art.where(["style_number LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:nav_search]}%", "%#{params[:nav_search]}%"]).distinct.page(params[:page]).per_page(18)
end
```